# How to insert buttons on top of a pyqtgraph plot area?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, qgraphicsscene

I'm working on a PyQt5 application, intending to use pyqtgraph to plot some data. I know pyqtgraph plot area already comes with mouse interaction modes, but I'd like to make this modes more visible to the user and add more functionalities (for example adding a button for ROI). To reach this, I want to add a frame with buttons on top of the plot area, similar to  [image: this example]
In addition, I'd like the buttons to stay in their place even when the window is resized and moved.

I've created a window with two GraphicView widget as PlotWidget (imbedding pyqtgraph):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_PlotsWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, PlotsWindow):
        PlotsWindow.setObjectName("PlotsWindow")
        PlotsWindow.resize(807, 650)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(PlotsWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.plot = PlotWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.plot.setObjectName("plot")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.plot)
        PlotsWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.dockWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QDockWidget(PlotsWindow)
        self.dockWidget_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(190, 100))
        self.dockWidget_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(524287, 300))
        self.dockWidget_2.setFeatures(QtWidgets.QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable|QtWidgets.QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable|QtWidgets.QDockWidget.DockWidgetVerticalTitleBar)
        self.dockWidget_2.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.BottomDockWidgetArea|QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea)
        self.dockWidget_2.setObjectName("dockWidget_2")
        self.dockWidgetContents_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("dockWidgetContents_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 5)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(5)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.signal = PlotWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.signal.setObjectName("signal")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.signal)
        self.dockWidget_2.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        PlotsWindow.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(8), self.dockWidget_2)

        self.retranslateUi(PlotsWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PlotsWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, PlotsWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PlotsWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("PlotsWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.dockWidget_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("PlotsWindow", "Time Series"))
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
```

And a frame with buttons widget:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class OverlayButtons(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(5)
        self.btn_1 = QPushButton()
        self.btn_1.setMinimumSize(QSize(20, 20))
        self.btn_1.setMaximumSize(QSize(20, 20))
        self.btn_1.setText('1')
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_1)
        self.btn_2 = QPushButton()
        self.btn_2.setMinimumSize(QSize(20, 20))
        self.btn_2.setMaximumSize(QSize(20, 20))
        self.btn_2.setObjectName("btn_2")
        self.btn_2.setText('2')
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_2)
```

I'm trying to insert the frame with buttons widget to the plot area this way:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import pyqtgraph as pg


class Plots(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Plots, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_PlotsWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.overlay_buttons = OverlayButtons(self.ui.plot)
        self.overlay_buttons.setParent(self.ui.plot)
        self.overlay_buttons.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Plots()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I managed to insert the frame with buttons within the plot area, but it's appearing on left-top corner. I'd like this on right-top corner.